# No me toma los estilos css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Tengo un problema con mi items de carrito.php y es que no me esta tomando los estilos css que ya le tengo definido, pero las demas items si estan tomando eso estilos y estoy agregando la misma cabezera para cada una de estos items por lo que no entiendo que estara fallando

Codigo carrito.php (Archivo que no me esta tomando el css)

```
<?php include("Templates/cabecera.php")?>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="product-list"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
<?php include("Templates/pie.php")?>
</html>
```

Archivo Main.js (Donde tengo el arreglo de productos)

```
const products = [
    {
    name: 'Diadema Logitec',
    image: './img/Diademas1.0.jpeg',
    price: 45000,
    quantity: 2,
    },
    {
    name: 'Iphone 7',
    image: './img/PorTatil.jpg', 
    price: 500,
    quantity: 4,
    },
    {
    name: 'Gafas de sol',
    image: './img/Teclado.jpg', 
    price: 100,
    quantity: 6,
    },
    {
    name: 'Juego comedor',
    image: './img/HDMI.jpg',  
    price: 320,
    quantity: 6,
    }
    ];
    function displayProducts() {
        const productList = document.getElementById('product-list');
        productList.innerHTML = '';
    
        products.forEach(product => {
            const total = product.price * product.quantity;
    
            const productCard = document.createElement('div');
            productCard.classList.add('product-card');
    
            productCard.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>${product.name}</h3>
                    <p>Precio: $${product.price}</p>
                    <p>Cantidad: ${product.quantity}</p>
                    <p>Total: $${total}</p>
                </div>`
            ;
    
            productList.appendChild(productCard);
        });
    }
    displayProducts();
```

Los estilos que estoy tratando de aplicar

```
.product-card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.product-card img {
    max-width: 1cm;  
    display: block;
    
}

.product-info {
    text-align: left;
    
}

.product-info p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

La cabecera que estoy esportando (Cabecerra.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home|DataMax</title>
    <!--Link Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css">
    <!--Link de Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Link de los inconos-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
</head>

<body class="Products">
    <nav>
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="Logo">

            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php" class="nav-link px-2">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="carrito.php" class="nav-link px-2">Cars</a></li>
                <li><a href="NewProduct.php" class="nav-link px-2">New Product</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2">
                    <a href="login.php" class="login">Login</a>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign-up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Archivo identico que si esta tomando los archivos css (Newporduct.php)

```
<?php include("Templates/cabecera.php")?>
<html> 
</body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="Name" class="input-padre" required>

            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="input-padre" required>

            <label for="Inventory">Inventory</label>
            <input type="number" name="Inventory" id="Inventory" class="input-padre" required>
            <button  class="enviar" onclick="return EnviarFormulario();">Crear Producto</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
<?php include("Templates/pie.php")?>
</html>
```

Les agradezco su ayuda :)

Comment: Una diferencia es que el archivo que importas en el que si funciona es app.js. El que no, es main.js. ¿Sera que te equivocaste de nombre?

Comment: Hola, no app.js son otras validaciones especial para ese archivo

Comment: Parece un problema de ambigüedad de rutas. Fíjate en el inspector, o en "ver código fuente", el vínculo completo que está tomando el llamado al CSS. Lo ideal es que sean rutas relativas, pero puedes probar con la ruta "absoluta": `/raiz_del_proyecto/css/estilos.css`